# Interface Builder NSScrollView not working with IB defined View

Tags: cocoa

I have defined a custom class with a drawRect called Drawing.   I have laid out the view in my NIB to contain an NSScrollView with a Drawing subview.   When I launch the program, the screen is blank.   Interestingly, when I create the documentView for the NSScrollView programmatically, I get an image in my scroll view.  When I use the instance for the nib in my setDocumentView, I get nothing.

So if the Drawing view is set in IB,

```
[_scrollViewWorkspace setDocumentView:_drawing]; //does not work.
```

But

```
[_scrollViewWorkspace setDocumentView:[[Drawing alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,[[_scrollViewWorkspace documentView ]bounds].size.width, [[_scrollViewWorkspace documentView] bounds ].size.height)]];
```

Works great!

Why can't I statically bind a drawing object in a NIB?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the custom class of the `NSView` subclass in the nib file to your custom class, at runtime, an instance of that class will be created using `initWithCoder:` rather than `initWithFrame:`.

You can easily check to see if this is the case by adding the following method to your custom `Drawing` view:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
   NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
   return [super initWithCoder:coder];
}
```

Then launch your app and see if `[Drawing initWithCoder:]` is logged to the console.

If you have overridden `initWithFrame:` in your `Drawing` class to do custom initialization (like set a custom image automatically), you will need to add that same code to the `initWithCoder:` method so that you end up with the same result:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
   if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
      // do custom initialization here

   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: I added the code to the class.   Nothing happens, nothing gets logged.  I am setting the document view in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching.  I put in a stub for initWithFrame and it logs the output from my NSLog there.   I don't think that initWithCoder is the right answer.  It doesn't tell me why the static binding to a view in IB is being ignored, yet an [alloc] init] of the same class works in code.

Comment: Even the drawRect in Drawing is being called before I set the documentView.  It is never called again after I set the view in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

When I laid the view out in Interface Builder I just dragged the custom view to the NSScrollView in the canvas.   I re-did the layout so that I used Embed->Scroll View  and it worked.

Bruce