# Simply embedding a custom NSView in an NSScrollView kills it

Tags: nsview, nsscrollview

As soon as I embed my custom NSView in a scroll view, nothing is drawn in my custom view.

To replicate the issue, I created a vanilla Cocoa app.  I subclassed NSView, and its `drawRect` handler, I do something simple like a red `fillRect`.  I verify this works as expected:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];
    // Drawing code here.
}
```

Back to IB, I click on my custom view, then go menu **Editor > Embed In > Scroll View**.

There is no longer a red rectangle in my view.  I've verified that my `drawRect` is no longer being called.

What gives?

I thought I'd come across a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754875/interface-builder-nsscrollview-not-working-with-ib-defined-view), but it was of no help.

Seems so simple.

Running Xcode 5.0.2 & OS10.9.1.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed... I had to add something like this to my custom view:

```
- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return NSMakeSize(960,540);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works for xcode 6 beta4 (10.9.4) using Swift (using adhoc large sizes)

```
func intrinsicContentSize() ->NSSize {
    return NSMakeSize(2000,2000)
}
```